# crystal report <=today error a string is required here

Tags: crystal-reports

anyone have an idea on this error

error a string is required here.

{orderrel.openrelease} = True and
{orderrel.needbydate} <= TODAY

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your date may be in text format.

try :

{orderrel.openrelease} = True and DateValue({orderrel.needbydate}) <= TODAY

if orderrel.needbydate is in a strange format parse it :

example for date in format yyyymmdd :

{orderrel.openrelease} = True and Date({orderrel.needbydate}[1 to 4], {orderrel.needbydate}[5 to 6], {orderrel.needbydate}[7 to 8])  <= TODAY

Answer (score 0):

Your needbydate data type is probably string.
Make sure that the data types on both sides of a comparison are the same.